# If $f$ is $C^1(U)$) , are $D_i f_j$ where $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $j=1,\ldots,m$ are all continuous on $U$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f$ is a function from an open set $U$ in $R^n$ to $R^m$ then $f=(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_m)$,

I am confused whether the following are true:

If $f$ is continuous on $U$, does that imply that $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ are continuous as well on $U$? If not what else do we need in order for this to hold?

If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $U$ ($C^1(U)$) , does that imply that the partial derivatives $D_i f_j$  where $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $j=1,\ldots,m$ are all continuous on $U$? If not, what else do we need ?

I just need to know whether these two statements are true so that I can use them in solving one of my problems. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, these statements are true. In fact, at least by some approaches, these are the definitions of the mentioned concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both afirmatives are corect. If $f$ is continuous, then  $f_i$ are continuous. If $f$ is continuous diferentiable, then $Df_i$ are continuous. But for the second statemet is not tue the converse, that is, if  $Df_i$ are continuous, does not imply that the function is $C^1$.